# Places to stay in Mainz, Germany for 1 to 2 hours?

Tags: germany, layovers, hotels

I will be in Mainz, Germany next month, but only for about 5-6 hours during a layover.

I can't seem to find anywhere online if there are hotels/hostels, or something of the sort that will allow a brief one or two hour stay to freshen up. I don't want to hang out in the airport as that would be just a drag.

I guess I could book a hotel for a full day, but to me that just seems like a waste of money for just one or two hours.

Are there such places in Mainz that would allow this?

Comment: Is there a reason specifically for Mainz and not, say, Frankfurt?

Comment: I would do Frankfurt as well, but I'm going to spend most of my time in Mainz. I guess since they are so close it won't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that Mainz is one of the hot spots for German "Karneval" or "Fastnacht", which basically turns the whole city into Pandemonium for about a week in Feb. See 
https://www.mainz.de/en/service/carnival-in-mainz.php

Finding accommodation during this time will quite difficult, but crashing parties and passing out on someone's couch is pretty normal (if you have the stomach for it).

Mainz is unusual for a stopover since it doesn't have an airport to speak off. Are you coming by train ?

Comment: Mainz is about 20 km away from Frankfurt Airport (FRA). It's less than 20 minutes by a local train.

Comment: I will actually be going in late Feb., I should have mentioned that. I will be taking the S-Bahn to Mainz from FRA.